# Background Task is not working for the first time but working fine on second click

Tags: java, android

I am creating an `android` application where I have to import data from the `server` when a menu item is clicked. As I have to wait for the importing to complete before doing the next thing, I am using `thread`. Now the problem is when I click the menu item for the first time, thread starts but does not complete the operation as expected nor does it saves the data in `SQLite` but when I click the menu item again, it works absolutely fine and the data from the server is successfully saved in my `SQLite`. I am not sure what's the problem here.
This is my function which I am calling on menu item click:

```
private void importServerData() {
        Utils.hideKeyboard(this);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 100);
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(username, password, domain, requestQueue);
        backgroundTask.start();
        synchronized (backgroundTask) {
            try {
                backgroundTask.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 100);
            HashMap<Integer, String> areasfromSQLite = Utils.getAreasfromSQLite();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Size: " + areasfromSQLite.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

and this is my BackgroundTask class:

```
static class BackgroundTask extends Thread {
        String username, pass, domainName;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;

        public BackgroundTask(String uname, String pass, String domainName, RequestQueue requestQueue) {
            this.username = uname;
            this.pass = pass;
            this.domainName = domainName;
            this.requestQueue = requestQueue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                Utils.fetchProductsFromServer(requestQueue, username, pass, domainName);
                Utils.fetchAreasFromServer(requestQueue, username, pass, domainName);
                Utils.fetchCustomersFromServer(requestQueue, username, pass, domainName);
                notify();
            }
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi! did you debug your code? can you say which function was called before which? try to see if the object references are the same for `backgroundTask` - would love to answer after it's clearer!

Comment: @nurnachman yes I did debug the code and flow is absolutely the same as in the second time. As far as the objects are concerned, you can see I am using same reference.

Comment: `this.username = uname;this.pass = pass;`
`this.domainName = domainName;`
`this.requestQueue = requestQueue;` Have you checked  a value by debugging?

Comment: @AnvarQuvandiqov can you please explain this? As I am using exact these lines in my constructor.

Comment: `Utils.fetchProductsFromServer(requestQueue, username, pass, domainName);` You use a queue so it looks as if that functions returns immediately instead of waiting for data from the server.